# Can anyone recommended useful reports to create from application log files using Splunk?

Tags: logging, splunk

I started looking in to Splunk and I really liked it,
So I started installing the server and all the needed forwarders to get the logs I want to track from my application.

Now I want to make the most out of it using the reports and dashboard,
Can anyone recommend useful reports to create from my application log files using Splunk ?

I know it's a beat comprehensive question,
But I can really use the help of someone who is already making the most out of this cool tool.

Comment: With no information about what your log files provide, it's impossible to answer this very broad and unspecific question.

Comment: @sheltem fair enough, Some of the logs provide failure massages and successful connection to database. The copying of files from one place to another and so on.

Comment: There is a place to start right there. Failure rates, Connection rates, copy rates over time. Rates by host, or by client being serviced. Performance data. and so on. You may also consider mapping your log format to the [CIM](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1621/) or coming up with a data model of your own and let people who are supporting your app figure out more of what they want to chart / report on using Pivot.

Comment: But to reiterate @sheltem's point. This is too broad of a question to answer. What is useful to you in supporting your application may or may not be useful or relevant to someone else supporting their application. The beauty of Splunk is you can develop what do you need to support your application and possibly even share that knowledge (this is where Splunk Apps and TAs are pretty cool)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are searching for some Splunk apps. According to [this document](http://dev.splunk.com/view/get-started/SP-CAAAESC):

> A Splunk App is a prebuilt collection of dashboards, panels and UI elements powered by saved searches and packaged for a specific technology or use case to make Splunk immediately useful and relevant to different roles.

You can easily find many Splunk apps in [Splunkbase](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/). For example:

- [Splunk App for Enterprise Security](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/263/)
- [Splunk App for VMware](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/725/)
- [Splunk App for Unix and Linux](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/273/)

Additionally, you can find more Splunk apps in its github.com repos. For example:

- https://github.com/splunk/splunk-app-splunkgit
- https://github.com/splunk/splunk-app-twitter
- https://github.com/splunk/splunk-app-sharepoint